# Installing Mysql on a VM under Alpine

Tags: mysql, alpine-linux

I'm trying to install and use mysql on Alpine. I'm using Docker to generate a VM under Alpine.
My Dockerfile is really simple :

```
FROM alpine:3.11.3

CMD sh
```

Once I've run the image created (using docker build // docker run image_id), I install Mysql :

```
apk add --update --upgrade mysql mysql-client
```

Then, I install the database :

```
mysql_install_db
```

The problem is that once I've done that and I try to "mysql", the machine returns this :

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

And when I try to do "mysqld -u root", it returns me this problem :

```
2020-08-26 10:07:55 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2020-08-26 10:07:55 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2020-08-26 10:07:55 0 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: No such file or directory
2020-08-26 10:07:55 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock ?
2020-08-26 10:07:55 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I understood that the file mysqld.sock serves the server to discuss with the client. I tried to create the directory mysqld and then to create the file mysqld.sock but it doesn't work. It returns me the same error but with a different return value.

```
(ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

At least, I don't want to use an existing image of mysql on Dockerhub.

Do anybody has an idea of what step is missing to make it work ?

Sorry if I'm not writing proper, I'm not a native english speaker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to successfully install and start mysql on an alpine container with these commands:

```
$ docker run -it --rm alpine:latest

/ # apk add mysql mysql-client
/ # mkdir /run/mysqld
/ # mysql_install_db
/ # mysqld -u root --data=./data &> /dev/null &
```

Testing connection:

```
/ # mysql -e "SELECT VERSION();"
+----------------+
| VERSION()      |
+----------------+
| 10.6.4-MariaDB |
+----------------+
```